# Should I test methods in Django models?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

Is there any reason to test model methods or I should assume that Django works properly and leave them untested?

Here is my model and couple methods from it:

```
class SlackTeam(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return self.users.filter(user_id=user_id).first()

    def deactivate(self):
        self.active = False
        self.initiator.access_token = ''
        self.initiator.save()
        self.initiator = None
        self.deactivated_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

        if hasattr(self, 'slackbot'):
            self.slackbot.delete()

    def set_initiator(self, user):
        self.initiator = user
        self.save(update_fields=['initiator'])

    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, team_id, name):
        return cls.objects.update_or_create(
            team_id=team_id, defaults={'name': name})[0]

    @classmethod
    def get_by_team_id(cls, team_id):
        return cls.objects.filter(team_id=team_id).first()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely assume that methods defined on the base `models.Model` class work. Your **own** methods - either custom ones or overridden - have to be tested, of course.

As a side note: the convention with Django models is to define methods working at the table level on the manager, not on the model itself so at least your `get_by_team_id` and possibly `initialize` should be defined on a custom manager.

Comment: What advantages I'll get if I move `get_team_by_id` and `initialize` methods to the custom manager?

Comment: Technically, none - but that's what most Django devs will expect. Sticking to conventions make your code base easier to get for newcomers, so consider this more as a social/readability/maintainability improvement (having table level methods on the manager makes clear which methods work on the instance and which ones work at the table level) than a purely technical one.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I guess this approach can be an interpretation of the Single Responsibility Principle when the manager has responsibility for table level operations, and the model is responsible for instance operations